# Alter CONSTRAINT or stored procedure only to check when insert not on update

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to alter a CONSTRAINT which CURRENTLY starts a stored procedure both when I insert OR update a table.

What I want is that the stored procedure ONLY activates on INSERT and NOT on update.

Is there a way to do this?

Kind regards.
--edit its a CONSTRAINT NOT A TRIGGER...SORRY ABOUT THAT.

Comment: I want to let the update go through like a normal update, but the insert use the stored procedure.
I mean I don't need the a trigger at all for UPDATE.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Constraints can no call procedures, but triggers can

Answer (score 0):

Sure make the trigger an INSERT trigger only, if you show the create trigger statement I can show you how

so instead of

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test
ON Table
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
....
```

you would do

```
ALTER TRIGGER Test
ON Table
AFTER INSERT
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean constraint? A constraint either applies or it doesn't and its purpose is to enforce integrity by either allowing or rejecting values or combinations of values in a column or table (see the [MSDN](http://%5BMSDN%5D%5B1%5D) for the full description). What you're describing **is** a trigger which means SQLMenace has provided you with your answer, albeit maybe you need to create a trigger and remove the constraint, if that's what it is. Perhaps you could provide the DDL which created your constraint in the first place for clarity?